# Incorrect values with concurrency example

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm working through an ebook and here I am doing this code:

```
func f(n int) {
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(n, ":", i)
    amt := time.Duration(rand.Intn(250))
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * amt)
  }
}

func ConcurrMain() {
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    go f(i)
  }
  fmt.Println("hi")
}
```

The problem is I'm retrieving different values with every run command through `goclipse`. It seems to work better when i do not execute the sleep command.

In any case, any explanation with step by step i thought would be beneficial in my learning of concurrency

Here's an example of my return value with time sleep:

```
4 : 0
1 : 0
6 : 0
0 : 0
5 : 0
7 : 0
8 : 0
2 : 0
3 : 0
9 : 0
9 : 1
hi
```

Then I run it again and I now get  with time sleep:

```
0 : 0
hi
1 : 0
```

And now a third time and I get  with time sleep:

```
0 : 0
hi
```

And this time **without sleep** i get:

```
1 : 0
1 : 1
1 : 2
1 : 3
1 : 4
1 : 5
1 : 6
1 : 7
1 : 8
3 : 0
3 : 1
4 : 0
4 : 1
4 : 2
9 : 0
6 : 0
6 : 1
6 : 2
2 : 0
2 : 1
2 : 2
2 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
2 : 6
2 : 7
2 : 8
2 : 9
7 : 0
7 : 1
7 : 2
7 : 3
7 : 4
7 : 5
7 : 6
5 : 0
5 : 1
5 : 2
5 : 3
5 : 4
5 : 5
5 : 6
5 : 7
5 : 8
5 : 9
9 : 1
1 : 9
8 : 0
3 : 2
hi
```

**I'm using goclipse under windows in case that information is pertinent**

**UPDATE**

It should be noted that this call is called from the main package as:

```
func main()
{
   lab.ConcurrMain()
}
```

**UPDATE2**

I added: `var wg sync.WaitGroup outside the func scope. I also added`wg.Add(1)`inside the`ConcurrMain`method just prior to`go f(i)`, then i also added`wg.Wait()`just after the`forloop which executes the go function`and then finally`wg.Done()`inside the`f()` method **and that seems to work but that answer wasnt in the ebook so i want to understand.

Comment: What exactly do you think is wrong?

Comment: @RickyA shouldn't it print all available permutations? Why is it printing only a few and never the same respnse. Also check update

Comment: ah: no, your main exits whether your go routines have finished or not. A solution for that would be to include a wait group as you mentioned.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/jHhXrbb1jC8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In go, a program is only running for as long as it's main goroutine is running. That is, the goroutine that originally runs the main function, if this exits, the entire program exits.

In the example you've originally given (the code snippets) there's nothing to enforce *when* the goroutines that you spin up in `ConcurrMain` will be scheduled and run. Before you added the `sync.WaitGroup` the main goroutine can exit before the additional goroutines have been scheduled.

If the main goroutine exits, the entire program exits and the other goroutines will not be executed. The main goroutine will not wait for the other goroutines unless you specifically ask it to, with a wait group.